# How to track impressions and clicks in two DFP accounts?

Tags: google-dfp

I would like to track impressions and clicks for the same creative in two DFP accounts. I did the following steps:
In first account (A) I created a creative of type image. 
In the second DFP account (B). I created a third-party creative and inserted the code for the creative from account (A), as following:

```
<a href='%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%https://www.example.com/' target='_blank' >
[DFP generated code for the image creative in account A]
</a>
```

The problem is that the tracking is not working, in the creative of type image. After searching I found that it is possible only via tracking lineitem which is available in DFP premium, whereas I have DFP for small businesses.

I also tried the following:
* In the  field Third-party impression URL in the creative of type image, I put a URL which opens the third-party creative when the URL requested by the browser:

```
 http://www.example.com/service/cookie.DFP.php?networkId=[network-id]&lineItem=[line-itme]&adUnit=[Ad-unit]&width=[width]&height=[height]
```

This URL is should be pinged for each creative of type image impression, but unfortunately No impressions registered in the third-party creative.

Could you please tell me if there is any turn around to achieve my goal!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue via creating a web service in the middle. The web service receives a link with the required parameters to generate DFP lineItem tags, in other words, it generates the code needed to render lineitem creatives. This link will be in an iframe which will be the content of one creative in the other DFP account _ account B _the iframe link accepts a click Macro which will be fired in 0px iframe. The Macro from the the account B will be sent as parameter to the web service, the web service will pass this parameter into the creative content, where a 0px iframe will be opened with a account B Macro link.